# Unable to get user image from Spotify API session

Tags: spotify, next-auth, spotify-app

I am trying to build a clone to `Spotify App` using their API and I only seem to be getting name , email and username from the API. Is there a way to get profile picture details?

Appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can access profile picture via API, see:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-current-users-profile

As you can see there is an "images" JSON array containing the picture at different resolutions:

[image]